# ASP.NET equivalent in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I am able to refer to body tag using code-behind during page load event in `ASP.NET Webforms` with this code here:

```
HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Master.FindControl("body1");
body.Style["background-image"] = Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/somepic.jpg");
body.Style["background-position"] = "0px 0px";
body.Style["background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
```

I am wondering if this is achievable with `ASP.NET MVC`? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Comment: And is there a reason you can't just have these style properties set in normal CSS?

Comment: MVC 5, not MVC core. Why am I doing this is because I want to load the image dynamically based on condition. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the style rules as a `String` value to your View-Model class and then render it inside your view:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public String BodyStyle { get; set; } = @"background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0;";
}
```

```
@model MyViewModel

<body style="@( this.Model.BodyStyle )">

</body>
```

But style rules really shouldn't be set directly on elements, you should use CSS in stylesheets or a `<style>` element instead, and if styling `<body>` is page-specific, then use a `class=""` on `<body>` or `<html>` instead, like so:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public String BodyClass { get; set; } = "foobar";
}
```

```
@model MyViewModel
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
body {
}

body.foobar {
    background-image: url("@Url.Content("~/images/somepic.jpg")");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body class="@( this.Model.BodyClass )">

</body>
```

---

As these are being applied to your `<body>` element which is likely inside your `_Layout.cshtml` (rather than being in every `.cshtml` file) you'll need to use a common view-model interface and dereference that in your `_Layout.cshtml`:

#### MyViewModel.cs

```
interface ICommonPageViewModel
{
    String BodyClass { get; }
}

class MyViewModel : ICommonPageViewModel
{
    public String BodyClass { get; set; }
}
```

#### _Layout.cshtml

```
@{
    ICommonPageViewModel cvm = (ICommonPageViewModel)this.Model;
}
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
body {
}

body.foobar {
    background-image: url("@Url.Content("~/images/somepic.jpg")");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
    </style>
    @RenderSection("head")
</head>
<body class="@( cvm.BodyClass )">
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```